# AWS IAM consistency issue

Tags: amazon-iam, hashicorp-vault

I'm using Hashicorp vault for creating users with the AWS Secrets-Engine.
I have an issue using the AWS credentials I get, probably because it takes time for all the AWS servers to be updated with the newly created user, as it stated [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/troubleshoot_general.html#troubleshoot_general_eventual-consistency)
[image]
I'm using Hashicorp Vault for creating AWS users in runtime, and use the credentials I get immediately. In practice, there could be a delay of up to a few seconds until I can actually use them. Besides performing some retry mechanism, I wonder if there is a real solution to this issue or at least a more elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

As AWS IAM promises eventual consistency, we cannot do anything better than delay and hope for the best. The bad part is that we don't know for how long should we sleep till the new keys reach all endpoints.

This is the problem with the behavior of IAM, not really a Vault issue. There's kinda workaround like this:

1. make a new temporary user, generate keys for it, hand the keys over to the Vault requester

2.use a non-temporary user, make a new key pair for it, etc

Didn't test it, but as an idea to try I guess it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

HashiCorp released a change in how they handle the dynamically created IAM users and the Vault provider now accounts for this delay.  https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-vault/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#260-november-08-2019  Since this update I rarely run into issues but they occur once in a while.